# Wget(Python) запись в папку

Tags: python, cmd

Здравствуйте. Помогите осуществить запись в папку библиотека(wget) никак не могу понять как сделать. Чтоб запись пошла в конкретную папку допустим в c:\awarZ\download буду благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте документацию. Вы можете скачать файл а потом скопировать его в нужную папку. Простой пример:

```
import wget
import os

directory = 'temp'
url = 'http://yourfile.com/thefile.zip'
filename = wget.download(url)
os.rename(filename,os.path.join(directory,filename))
```

Только папка должна существовать.

Comment: Вместо os.rename(), просто напрямую папку как аргумент передайте: `wget.download(url, out=directory)`

Comment: Пробую, что-то не хочет, делал по вашим способам, один способ скачивает только файл, но не записывает его в папку, другой вообще не рабочий.

Comment: @EvleapsCorp. выложите ваш код полностью. И папка существует?

Comment: @EvleapsCorp. еще важно чтобы были права на запись в папку. Возможно скрипт следует запускать от имени Администратора.

Comment: @EvleapsCorp. добавьте его в сообщение и выделите через ctrl+k чтобы текст оформился как код.

Comment: добавил, вверху коммент

Answer (score -1):

```
def norm_surge_take_url():
    import wget, os, sys
    norm_surge_takeURL = input(" norm/SURGE_TAKE/ : URL=TRUE#~ ")

    norm_surge_take_true = True
    if norm_surge_take_true == True:
        wget.download(norm_surge_takeURL)

        import surge_download_info
        surge_download_info.norm_download_info()

    elif norm_surge_take_true == False:
        print(" ERROR_DOWNLOAD : URL_WRONG")
```

Comment: не понятно что за surge_download_info. Да и у вас тут не указано что в папку необходимо писать. Используйте мой пример или комментарий @jfs: wget.download(url, out=directory). Только скрипт от администратора запускайте и проверяйте что директория существует.